# Criar ActionFilter para login "Anônimo"

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

Pesquisei na internet mas não encontrei a resposta para o que eu queria.
Possuo o simples código abaixo que verifica se o usuário está autenticado ou não no meu ActionFilter

```
public class FiltroLogin : ActionFilterAttribute
{
    public override void OnActionExecuted(ActionExecutedContext filterContext)
    {
         if (filterContext.HttpContext.Session["Login"] == null)
        {
            filterContext.Controller.TempData["msg"] = "Você precisa realizar o login para acessar esta página";
            filterContext.Result = new RedirectToRouteResult(new RouteValueDictionary(new { Controller = "Login", Action = "Index" }));
        }
    }
}
```

Mas tenho uma página em um mesmo Controller que não queria que executasse essa verificação se está logado ou não. Então simplesmente criei este outro ActionFilter em que não faz nada e coloquei em cima do método do controller que não quero que verifique se está logado ou não:

```
public class FiltroAnonimo: ActionFilterAttribute
{
    public override void OnActionExecuted(ActionExecutedContext filterContext)
    {

    }
}
```

Mas não está funcionando, ele ainda continua voltando para a tela de Login sendo que não é o que quero que aconteça.
O que devo colocar no FiltroAnonimo para que ele ignore a função do FiltroLogin?

Comment: Não vejo utilidade nisso tudo. `Request.IsAuthenticated` + `[Authorize]` já resolve isso pra você.

Comment: Sim, eu vi sobre esse tipo. Mas e se um dia eu precisar um dia criar meu próprio filtro personalizado mas em alguns métodos não precisar utiliza-lo em algum método no mesmo controller?

Comment: Como eu disse, `Request.IsAuthenticated` + `[Authorize]`. Não precisa reinventar a roda.

Answer (score 2):

A simples decoração de [`[Authorize]`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.authorizeattribute(v=vs.118).aspx) nos seus *Controllers* e métodos já verifica se o usuário é anônimo ou não.

```
[Authorize]
public class MeuController
{
    ...
}
```

Ou

```
public class MeuController
{
    [Authorize]
    public ActionResult MinhaAction()
    {
        ...
    }
}
```

Se você precisa de algo mais específico, pode usar [`Request.IsAuthenticated`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httprequest.isauthenticated(v=vs.110).aspx):

```
public class MeuController
{
    public ActionResult MinhaAction()
    {
        if (Request.IsAuthenticated) { ... }
    }
}
```